# How to inspect the css attributes

Tags: google-chrome

Can the attributes of a css class be inspected using google chrome ?

When I inspect the element I can view the css class name but I can't view the attributes of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIght click on the area you want to inspect, and click 'Inspect element'. It will show all of the definitions of the CSS stylings that it has associated with it. See here[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Developer Tools allows for inspecting of CSS attributes. Selecting *View > Developer > Developer Tools* should bring up a panel in the bottom of the window, and on the right side will be all the CSS goodies. See [@Chris'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398645/1267663) image.